# Upgrading to silverstripe 4.3 shows "exceeded the timeout of 60 seconds"

Tags: silverstripe, composer-php

When I run this command it shows an error:

```
C:\wamp64\www>php upgrade-code.phar recompose --write

Upgrading PHP constraint
========================

 Done.

Rebuilding dependencies
=======================

 ! [NOTE] Trying to re-require all packages

 * Requiring php:">=5.6" ......... ✔
 * Requiring silverstripe/recipe-core:"4.3.0" ....................................................................................... ✔
 * Requiring silverstripe/recipe-cms:"*" .................................................................................................................................... ✔
 * Requiring silverstripe/reports:"*" ............................................................................................................................................... ✔
 * Requiring silverstripe/siteconfig:"*" ............................................................................................................................. ✔
 * Requiring silverstripe-themes/simple:"*" .............................................................................................................................. ✔

In Process.php line 1236:

  The process "composer update --working-dir="C:\Users\PKGUPT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ss-upgrader-5c53e7ac309a8" --prefe
  r-stable --ignore-platform-reqs --no-plugins" exceeded the timeout of 60 seconds.


recompose [-d|--root-dir ROOT-DIR] [-w|--write] [-S|--strict] [-R|--recipe-core-constraint [RECIPE-CORE-CONSTRAINT]] [--cwp-constraint [CWP-CONSTRAINT]] [-P|--composer-path [COMPOSER-PATH]] [-Q|--quick]
```

Comment: Do you have a max execution time set in your CLI php.ini? You could adjust it, or something like `php -d max_execution_time=0 composer upgrade-code.phar ...` (zero is the default setting for CLI)